# (OS X) How do I bind "enter" to a combination of keys at the left side of my keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to bind "enter" to a combination of keys at the left side of my keyboard. How do I go about doing this? (I would like the combination of keys to be Ctrl+Shift+Q, or maybe there is a better one out there?). It's sort of becoming tedious to reach around or let go of the mouse from my right hand whenever I enter something.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [this](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en), worth checking out

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ENTER, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</identifier>
  </item>
</root>
```